# When does @IBInspectable get set?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a few properties set as `@IBInspectable`, so I can edit them in the Interface Builder, but during runtime when are those properties set?

I tried using them during the init but they were not set yet.

This is what I am trying to do. But I can't even move the Timer Init to the TimerView Init because the `@IBInspectable` vars are not set by the time the init is called.

```
class TimerView {
    var timer:Timer? = Timer(timeInterval: time1, alertTimeInterval: time2)
    @IBInspectable var time1: Double = 0
    @IBInspectable var time: Double = 0
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like anything set in IB, it will be set when the xib file is loaded. You want to set your timer in awakeFromNib()

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    timer = //IBInspectable elements now set
}
```

Comment: you need to call super.awakeFromNib()